# as3 multiple key_down moving object

Tags: actionscript-3

My object "araba" is not moving when KEY_DOWN happening waiting for your comments thx !

```
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
```

`stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, basili);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, degil);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, giris);


var yukari:Boolean = false;
var asagi:Boolean = false;
var sola:Boolean = false;
var saga:Boolean = false;
var hiz:Number = 5;
var araba:MovieClip=new araba();    
var masa:MovieClip =new masa();


function giris(event:Event):void
{
if ( sola && !saga ) {
araba.x -= hiz;
araba.rotation = 270;
}
if( saga && !sola ) {
araba.x +=hiz;
araba.rotation = 90;
}
if( yukari && !asagi ) {
araba.y -= hiz;
araba.rotation = 0;
}
if( asagi && !yukari ) {
araba.y += hiz;
araba.rotation = 180;
}
if( sola && yukari && !saga && !asagi ) {
araba.rotation = 315;
}
if( saga && yukari && !sola && !asagi ) {
araba.rotation = 45;
}
if( sola && asagi && !saga && !yukari ) {
araba.rotation = 225;
}
if( saga && asagi && !sola && !yukari) {
araba.rotation = 135;
}
if( araba.y < masa.y ){
araba.y = masa.height;
}
if( araba.y > masa.height ){
araba.y = masa.y;
}
if( araba.x < masa.x ){
araba.x = masa.width;
}
if( araba.x > masa.width ){
araba.x = masa.x;
}
} 
function basili (event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
switch( event.keyCode )
{
case Keyboard.UP:
yukari = true;
break;
case Keyboard.DOWN:
asagi = true;
break;
case Keyboard.LEFT:
sola = true;
break;
case Keyboard.RIGHT:
saga = true;
break;
}
}
function degil(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
switch( event.keyCode )
{
case Keyboard.UP:
yukari = false;
break;
case Keyboard.DOWN:
asagi = false;
break;
case Keyboard.LEFT:
sola = false;
break;
case Keyboard.RIGHT:
saga = false;
break;
}
}
<code>`

Answer (score 0):

I've looked at your code and it looks fine to me, but why don't you try tracing and see what happens?

Comment: since im am an amateur programmer and this homework is urgent i don't really know how to trace it :)

Comment: I'm going to post another alternative.

Answer (score 0):

```
        private var leftKeyIsDown:Boolean;
        private var rightKeyIsdown:Boolean
        private var downKeyIsDown:Boolean;
        private var upKeyIsDown:Boolean;





        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDown); //when key is down, go to this function
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUp); //when key is up, go to this function
        gameloop();

        private function gameLoop(e:Event):void //this function runs 30 times every second, due to 30fps
        {
        playerControl();
        }

        private function keyDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void 
        {
                //trace Event and KeyCode, when we trace this we get I.D number from key
                //trace(e.keyCode);
                if (e.keyCode == 37)
                {
                    //left key is pressed
                    leftKeyIsDown = true;
                }
                if (e.keyCode == 38)
                {
                    //up key is pressed
                    upKeyIsDown = true;
                }
                if (e.keyCode == 39)
                {
                    //right key is pressed
                    rightKeyIsdown = true;
                }
                if (e.keyCode == 40)
                {
                    //down key is pressed
                    downKeyIsDown = true;
                }

        }

    private function keyUp(e:KeyboardEvent):void 
    {
        //if our left key is released
        if (e.keyCode == 37)
        {
            //left key is released
            leftKeyIsDown = false;
        }
        if (e.keyCode == 38)
        {
            //up key is released
            upKeyIsDown = false;
        }
        if (e.keyCode == 39)
        {
            //right key is released
            rightKeyIsdown = false;
        }
        if (e.keyCode == 40)
        {
            //down key is released
            downKeyIsDown = false;
        }


    }

    private function playerControl():void 
    {
        //if left is currently down
        if (leftKeyIsDown)
        {
            //move ship to the left
            ship.x -= 5;  //subtract 5 from ships position evey loop, 

        }   

        //if right is currently down
        if (rightKeyIsdown)
        {
            //move ship to the right
            ship.x += 5;  //subtract 5 from ships position evey loop, 
        }   

        //if up is currently down
        if (upKeyIsDown)
        {
            //move ship up
            ship.y -= 5;  //subtract 5 from ships position evey loop, 
        }   

        //if left is currently down
        if (downKeyIsDown)
        {
            //move ship down
            ship.y += 5;  //subtract 5 from ships position evey loop, 
        }   
    }
```

replace ship with your object.

This is a template, i've commented too.

Please tell me if this is useful, it doesn't fix your code, I know.

But hopefully you can adapt this to it.

Comment: but as i seen it doesn't moving with angle. Does it ?

Comment: i've implemented my objects through this code but still it didn't work at all.But still thx for effort.